# User-Agent affects Dropbox shared links download

Tags: curl, dropbox, user-agent

I stumbled upon a weird Dropbox behaviour when downloading shared links. Consider the following curl commands:

```
curl -H 'User-Agent: curl/7.51.0' -v https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbgs6wqmlqp78sg/demo-pic.jpg\?dl\=0
# ...
# < HTTP/1.1 302 Found
# ....
# < Location: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/yYOt5GIzU8aFEuRve5tI6THhrxlQ8Hq5PCgXmSe6YHM81iKP2SFKlaJCCCSpE9hS/file
```

This returns a 302 redirect with the location to the actual image file. But when I change the User-Agent, I get a different result:

```
curl -H 'User-Agent: foobar' -v https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbgs6wqmlqp78sg/demo-pic.jpg\?dl\=0
# ...
# < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
# ...
```

And this returns a HTML page from dropbox with all the login stuff, picture preview etc.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any documentation on this, and what User-Agent will return what return status code.

I mean, I could just set the `User-Agent: curl/7.51.0` and rely on this, but how long will it dropbox take to also change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem trying to pull a file from Dropbox using Java. It worked perfectly for curl, but failed for Java (the HTML page was returned instead). Setting the User-Agent header in my Java app to `curl/7.54.0` worked, but that seemed like an awful hack.

The [link](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201) in Greg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143957/1574374) pointed me to the solution:

> To force a browser to download the contents of a link rather than display it, you can use dl=1 as a query parameter in your URL. For example:
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1b2c3d4ef5gh6/example.docx?dl=1

So I replaced the `dl=0` in the URL with `dl=1`, and everything works perfectly -- no need to change the User-Agent header. There are still 301 and 302 redirects to follow, but that's not a problem for `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and most other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox may offer the raw file content via a redirect like this for some User-Agents, e.g., for curl where it's unlikely the user wants the HTML of the preview page. This isn't documented or guaranteed though, so I wouldn't recommend relying on it.

There are some documented URL parameters you can use to manage the behavior of shared links though:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201